# I'm 20 and just completed high school. How do I apply for a 3-month Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I had to drop out of high school due to depression and other personal  issues. I just finished high school and want to travel to Europe so that I can better understand the world. And it'll be a good time away from all the negativity and issues I had. Any problems I'll have? (My parents are going to sponsor)

Comment: I don't want to book the tickets and not get the visa. That's the part I'm scared off

Comment: What is your citizenship country?

Comment: Please make it more obvious if you dropped out of school or finished it.

Comment: @asfarnorthaspossible I take it from the title that they finished high school

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that you just finished high school, you are currently not student in any educational institution. Your situation is very open to be understood as over-stay or illegal immigration. I am afraid that your application will be possible subject to fail. But if you were a college student, I would say that you can 
easily get the visa by providing necessary documentaries.

If I assume that you dropped out of the high school, your situation is even worse.

Even if the situations are like this, if I had no monetary problems, I would apply for visa.

Comment: I assume that the OP is an USA citizen, will have a return ticket when setting out and stands a good chance on getting a stamp in his passport on arrival in most European countries, including Schengen and the UK, so does not need to apply for a visa.

Comment: @Willeke why do you assume a US citizen?  It seems unlikely to me that a US citizen would know what Schengen visas are without also knowing that US citizens don't need them.

Comment: High school, use of English and general information out of the question, but it is a guess. (US=USA)